# wordpress: get all post embedded images

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to get a post embedded images but the only methods I see over the internet are

```
        $attachments = get_posts(array(
            'post_parent'       => get_the_ID(),
            'post_type'         => 'attachment',
            'posts_per_page'    => $n,
            'post_mime_type' => 'image'
        ));


        $attachments = get_children(array(
            'post_parent'       => get_the_ID(),
            'post_type'         => 'attachment',
            'posts_per_page'    => $n,
            'post_mime_type' => 'image'
        ));

        $attachments = get_attached_media('image', get_the_ID());
```

but this gives only the attached images I want all the images in a post even if they are not attached to that post `'post_parent' => get_the_ID()`

I think this is the WordPress way of attaching images it sounds like a one-to-many relationship
an image can only be attached to one post

any idea? thanks in advance

Comment: If they are not attached to the post, then they are likely just part of the _content_ of the post. Meaning, you would need to get that, and then fish them out of there yourself.

Comment: yeah this is possible with a regex but i have i more complex function and i think this will make it more complicated in my situation , i'm just wondering if there is some quick fix for that

Comment: If the images where just inserted into the content somewhere via the editor, then there _is_ no other connection between the post and the image.